# How do I find out details about an error showed iby "brew services list"?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I want test my postgres13 service on mac by using "brew services list".
I got following:

```
$ brew services list
Name       Status  User      Plist
postgresql error   gerd      /Users/gerd/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

How can I find out details about this error?

In the /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log logfile (listed in homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist) is no error:

```
2021-01-28 17:36:59.429 CET [41194] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27), 64-bit
2021-01-28 17:36:59.430 CET [41194] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2021-01-28 17:36:59.431 CET [41194] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-01-28 17:36:59.431 CET [41194] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-01-28 17:36:59.436 CET [41195] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-01-28 17:35:44 CET
2021-01-28 17:36:59.440 CET [41194] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

My database work and I can connect with psql.